# How to get syntactic coloration for dist files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

There is a standard for providing files that may have an unversioned counterpart. That standard consists in suffixing the filename with `.dist`, so for example `phpunit.xml` becomes `phpunit.xml.dist`. How can I tell vim that whenever it sees that suffix, it should remove it when attempting to determine the filetype?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this into

> ~/.vim/ftdetect/dist.vim

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.dist
    \ execute 'doautocmd filetypedetect BufRead' fnameescape(expand('<afile>:r'))
```

Basically we strip the `.dist` extension and re-execute the filetype-detection routine. A similar code is used in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` to detect filetype for `*.bak`, `*.old` and a few other "generic" extensions. Unfortunately, `*.dist` isn't found there.

Comment: Thank you! When I think of all these years I wasted not asking this question…